# $\sum_{n \geq 0} g(x) f(n,x)$ converges uniformly/normally $\iff$ $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n,x)$ converges uniformly/normally?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Consider a series of functions where there are two expressions: $g(x)$, dependent only on $x$, and $f(x,n)$, dependent both on $n$ and $x$

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} g(x) f(n,x)$$

An example could be

$$\sum_{n \geq 0} x^3 \frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$$
Where $g(x)=x^3$ and $f(n,x)=\frac{1}{x^2+n^2}$.

My question is: does $\sum_{n \geq 0} g(x) f(n,x)$ converges **uniformly**/**normally** if and only if $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n,x)$ converges  **uniformly**/**normally**?

(It is obvious that $\sum_{n \geq 0} g(x) f(n,x)$ converges **absolutely** if and only if $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n,x)$ converges  **absolutely** but I'm not sure if the same is valid for **normal** and **unform** convergence).

Comment: If $g(x_0) = 0$, then clearly $\sum g(x_0)f(n,x_0)$ converges absolutely, whether or not $\sum f(n,x_0)$ converges. If $g$ is not bounded, $\sum f(n,x)$ may converge uniformly or normally without $\sum g(x) f(n,x)$ converging uniformly or normally. If $1/g$ isn't bounded, $\sum g(x) f(n,x)$ may converge uniformly or normally without $\sum f(n,x)$ doing so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If we consider series of the form  $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n)x^n g(x)$ (power series if there wasn't $g(x)$),  the radius of convergence $r$ of $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n)x^n$ should give the interval of (absolute) convergence of $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n)x^n g(x)$, that is $(-r,r)$. Then I know that in any interval $(-\delta , \delta) \,\,,\, \delta<r$ the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n)x^n$ converges normally. So from here I cannot conclude, in general, that the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} f(n)x^n g(x)$ converges normally in the same interval, but can I do that, if $g(x)$ is bounded?

Comment: If $g$ is bounded on the interval $(-\delta,\delta)$, then you have normal convergence. Note that $\sup \{ \lvert f(n)x^ng(x)\rvert : x \in (-\delta,\delta)\} \leqslant \sup \{ \lvert f(n)x^n\rvert : x \in (-\delta,\delta)\} \cdot \sup \{ \lvert g(x)\rvert : x \in (-\delta,\delta)\}$. And if you multiply the terms of a convergent series of non-negative terms by a constant, you get a convergent series. By the comparison test, $\sum f(n)x^n g(x)$ then converges normally on $(-\delta,\delta)$. But if $g$ is unbounded on $(-\delta,\delta)$, then $f(n)x^ng(x)$ typically is unbounded there too.

Comment: (The non-typical cases being $f(n) = 0$, or that $g$ is bounded outside $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ for every $\varepsilon > 0$, and doesn't grow too fast for $x\to 0$, so that its growth can be compensated by $x^n$.)